# Broadcast data_sms_received with port

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I'm writing an app used for testing SMS receivers. Currently I am a bit stuck on the use case of receiving a Data SMS to a specific port. I have no trouble sending a real Data SMS but I would like to just simulate it by spoofing the broadcast event.

Now to where I am stuck: I need to set the intent data in code.

In XML it looks like this

```
<data
  android:scheme="sms"
  android:host="*"
  android:port="12345" />
```

The intent filter it hast to match is constructed like this

```
intentFilter.addDataScheme("sms");
intentFilter.addDataAuthority("*", PORT);
```

My question is how do I create the correct URI from the above XML?

Answer (score 2):

Found the [solution](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)

> `<scheme>://<host>:<port>[<path>|<pathPrefix>|<pathPattern>]`

```
Uri dataUri = Uri.parse("sms://*:"+port);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED")
                .putExtra("pdus", new Object[]{pdu})
                .setDataAndNormalize(dataUri);
```